# My onClickListener is not working anymore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, onclicklistener

I tried my best to make something work with my recyclerView and my `onClickListener`. Two days ago I have no idea how but I made it work.
Today I tried to work on my app again, and well it's not working anymore. I changed nothing in the code, so I don't get it.

My adapter class with my onClickListener code in my onBindViewHolder :

```
class LvlAdapter( var items: List<Lvl>, private var c:Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LvlAdapter.LvlViewHolder>() {

    val limit = 10;

    inner class LvlViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var titleLvl: TextView
        var buttonLvl: ImageView

        init {
            titleLvl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleLvl)
            buttonLvl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLvl)
        }

        fun bind(lvl: Lvl) {
            titleLvl.text = lvl.title
            buttonLvl.setImageResource(lvl.button)
        }

    }
    // return the viewHolder with the item view, but inflate from xml to view first
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LvlViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lvl_card, parent, false)
        return LvlViewHolder(itemView)

    }
    // what we bind in the viewHolder (ce qu'on injecte)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LvlViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var lvl = items[position]
        holder.bind(lvl)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            
            var mode1 = items.get(position)
            var title1 : String = mode1.title

            var intent = Intent(c, GameQuestionsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", title1)

            c.startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
    // return a size of the items
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if(items.size > limit){
            return limit
        } else {
        return items.size
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and run the app again

Comment: Please elaborate what "not working" means in this case.

Comment: When I click on one of my items in my recyclerView, I feel like the onClickListener work because it those click, the "click action works" but I see just a white flash for a couple of sec and then it goes back on the same activity with my recyclerView.

Comment: Based on this last comment, you are probably launching `GameQuestionsActivity` but it is failing to start for some reason. Check your logcat for errors and post what you find there.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.